# How to find what server a specific web page is on?

Tags: html

I have some old web pages that I want to delete but I can't find them anywhere on the server and as the website has been previously moved they may be on an old server somewhere but because I took over the job at a later stage I have no idea where they were moved from. The webpage is

http://www.absolutetradesupplies.com.au/greenhouse-films.html

If someone could tell me how to find the location of this page would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a *whois* lookup to get the IP. 
This will return lots of information like contact details, your registrar and more. Just look for the part with the servers IP.

Now find that server, logon and find your web root for apache2 by default this is /var/www/ your file should be here.

Comment: Thanks I tried whois but it returns the address of the website not that particular page. It says the server is MSI but there are no files on the MSI server because the DNS is redirected to another server (SPnet). The developers who have built the new website haven't given me the FTP details for this server but they say that the particular page is not on the server.

Comment: The IP is 122.248.236.136. That is what you were after right? So tired today :S

Comment: Find the server with the IP of 
122.248.236.136 and delete the files in the root directory (apache2: /var/www/)

Comment: cool thanks Conner I will tell the developer that it must be on their server.